# Android TextView Multiline Formatting

Tags: android, textview, string-formatting, multiline

These two line from my logcat are strings that were formatted with String.fortmat()

```
04-19 13:57:44.918 26962-26962/ts.kiosk.app.checkout E/java.lang.StackTraceElement: "Tendered Amount:                    Rs.     0.00"
04-19 13:57:44.919 26962-26962/ts.kiosk.app.checkout E/java.lang.StackTraceElement: "Change Due:                         Rs.     0.00"
```

you can see both line are the same exact length but in the Text View the string are not exactly like they were formatted to be:

```
String.format("%-25s Rs. %2$8.2f", "Tendered Amount:", formatCentsToCurrency(checkoutBasket.tenderedAmount));

String.format("%-25s Rs. %2$8.2f", "Change Due:", formatCentsToCurrency(checkoutBasket.changeDue));
```

So this is how its aligned in the TextView:

```
"Tendered Amount:                       Rs.     0.00"
"Change Due:                         Rs.     0.00"
```

I'm thinking my TextView is messing up the formatting somewhow:

```
                       <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text_receipt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        style="@style/popUpReceiptText"
                      android:text="@string/popup_detail_description_default"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

[image: actual TextEdit]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what the problem is? It's a bit hard to tell from your description

Comment: I added Text to show how it misaligned in the TextView

Comment: Have you tried using tabs? `\t`

Comment: I added screen shot and no I cannot use tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the correct answer, and actually so simple I should have discovered earlier:

I simply added:

```
android:typeface="monospace"
```

to my TextView

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. I just wasted an hour trying to figure this out too, I never thought about the font.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices do not use monospace fonts by default, so even with controlled spacing, it will be difficult to align left AND right in the same TextView.

You can solve this by changing the layout. An idea would be implementing 2 TextViews per row, one with `alignParentLeft=true` and the other with `alignParentRight=true` within a `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: hmmm , ok but won't work as I have varying number of tokens in each line (can be more than 2  and even 3 or 4). I think you can specify monospace font while drawing Text on canvas?

Comment: You can use Calligraphy (https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to render 3rd party fonts. But hands down the easiest way is to use 4 TextViews and toggle `GONE` or `VISIBLE`.

Comment: @ Some Noob Student:   Thanks but its Not hands down easiest given the parameters of my question in which I have an array of String formatted tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Textview you can try to use TableLayout that will automatically allign your values in rows and columns.